# ScalaTest: Running a test 50 times

Tags: scala, scalatest

Is there a simple way to implement failure tolerance in ScalaTest? I'm looking to run the same test 50 times and give it a tolerable error margin, e.g. 10%.

In the above case, the test would only pass if 45 out of 50 tests were successful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to do that is to override `withFixture` and rerun failed tests using whatever algorithm makes sense in your particular case. For inspiration, I'd suggest you look at the `Retries` trait in ScalaTest itself. The Scaladoc is here:

http://doc.scalatest.org/2.1.0/index.html#org.scalatest.Retries

The actual source code for `Retries` is here:

https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/Retries.scala

Comment: Both links in this answer seem to be out of date

Answer (score 6):

Here is an addition to [Bill Venners](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1102413/bill-venners) proposed solution. I needed to implement a few retries for flickering/unstable tests.

```
val retries = 4

override def withFixture(test: NoArgTest) = {
  if (isRetryable(test)) withFixture(test, retries) else super.withFixture(test)
}

def withFixture(test: NoArgTest, count: Int): Outcome = {
  val outcome = super.withFixture(test)
  outcome match {
    case Failed(_) | Canceled(_) => if (count == 1) super.withFixture(test) else withFixture(test, count - 1)
    case other => other
  }
}
```

Extended test class for retries (`with Retries`) and each test with `taggedAs Retryable`. Such tests when needed will be retried up to 4 times.

Answer (score 2):

Scala-check may be a good solution for that.
http://www.scalacheck.org/